# http://stackauth.com/0.8/sites down

Tags: bug, status-completed

I realize you may be shaking something out but in case you are not aware:

http://stackauth.com/0.8/sites is returning

```
{ "api_sites": [] }
```

Comment: @sys - and what about the endpoint? http://instantrimshot.com/index.php?sound=rimshot&play=true

Comment: Yep, it's down. Darn it, I can't take screenshots of the new version of Droidstack =)

Comment: Uh.. API regression much? The `/stats` call doesn't return meta data anymore (such as site name, etc..)

Comment: @felix - yea, I noticed that. I guess it is considered redundant =-| I am going to bug it.

Comment: looks fix'd now

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed.

Its worth noting that if stackauth is down, the "sites" data served up the API will eventually go down as well.  Its cached fairly heavily, but is still ultimately stackauth sourced.

Comment: interesting. sounds like a bit of fault tolerance might be in order. i can't imagine this data as any degree of volatile so perhaps a persistent cache would be a good idea.

Comment: something to keep in mind is that there are many people building on the api. when a component of the api fails, our apps fail. the user doesn't think 'oh, some part of the underlying technology failed due to lack of fault tolerance' they think 'wow, this app sucks. this dude/company really doesn't deserve any more of my attention'. first impressions are irrevocable.

Comment: @code poet - we're still in beta.  What's the difference between broken because of service outage, and broken because a method signature changed?

Comment: .. response coming... i want to give this some attention but i am just taking a short break from a cruel challenge and need to stay in zone.

Comment: I cannot mark this as answered because I see it as an avoidable point of failure.